# Validate decimal values up to x digits greater than zero

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, model-view-controller, decimal

I am trying to create a Regular Expression Validation that allows

a) Decimal numbers up to 3 decimal places which are greater than zero
b) Either positive or negative but non-zero numbers up to 3 decimal places

the following items with (+) must be validated while (-) should not for

**(a)**

```
(+) 0,872
(+) 0,87
(+) 0,8
(+) 0,001
(+) 1,000
(+) 1,00
(+) 1
(+) 80,546
(+) 80,000
(+) 81,001

(-) 0
(-) 0,0
(-) 0,00
(-) 0,000
```

also

**(b)** is most possible the same thing which allows minus(-) before numbers.

Best possible result I have achieved for (a) is

```
^(?=,*[0-9])\d*\,?\d{1,3}$
```

What is the best solution for the problem?

P.S. : I am using this as a MVC Model RegularExpression attribute value with jQuery validation. So Python and other RegExp engine validations are out of question.

Comment: You don't need regexp for this. Are you aware that two simple `if` statements are enough? If RegExp is not necessary for you, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Of course I can handle the situation either client or server side but company requires errors shown as other validation errors. This si why I force to write it with RegExp.

Comment: Still, you don't need RegExp to detect errors. What errors do you want to catch?

Comment: Allow decimal values greater than zero up to 3 decimal digits with localized display (use . as thousands seperator and , as decimal seperator) But display error for zero (0 or 0,00 etc) values.

Comment: Ok, what if number is `0,534234` - should it output error also? If so, should it be different than the `0` number error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex matches all of your examples and their negative counterparts (and rejects your non-matching examples) plus a few other test cases:

```
^-?(?!0(,0+)?$)\d+(,\d{1,3})?$
```

[DEMO on RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E-%3F%28%3F!0%28%2C0%2B%29%3F%24%29%5Cd%2B%28%2C%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D%29%3F%24&input=0%2C872%0A0%2C87%0A0%2C8%0A0%2C001%0A1%2C000%0A1%2C00%0A1%0A80%2C546%0A80%2C000%0A81%2C001%0A-0%2C872%0A-0%2C87%0A-0%2C8%0A-0%2C001%0A-1%2C000%0A-1%2C00%0A-1%0A-80%2C546%0A-80%2C000%0A-81%2C001%0A%0A0%0A0%2C0%0A0%2C00%0A0%2C000%0A-0%0A-0%2C0%0A-0%2C00%0A-0%2C000%0A%0A0%2C123786789889%0A%2C657657567%0A%2C00%0A%2C123%0A)

---

To allow for `.` as a thousand separator use:

```
^-?(?!0(\.000)*(,0+)?$)\d+(\.\d{3})*(,\d{1,3})?$
```

[DEMO on RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E-%3F%28%3F!0%28%2C0%2B%29%3F%24%29%5Cd%2B%28%2C%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D%29%3F%24&input=0%2C872%0A0%2C87%0A0%2C8%0A0%2C001%0A1%2C000%0A1%2C00%0A1%0A80%2C546%0A80%2C000%0A81%2C001%0A-0%2C872%0A-0%2C87%0A-0%2C8%0A-0%2C001%0A-1%2C000%0A-1%2C00%0A-1%0A-80%2C546%0A-80%2C000%0A-81%2C001%0A%0A0%0A0%2C0%0A0%2C00%0A0%2C000%0A-0%0A-0%2C0%0A-0%2C00%0A-0%2C000%0A%0A0%2C123786789889%0A%2C657657567%0A%2C00%0A%2C123%0A)

Comment: That totally solved the problem. Thank you very much for the solution.

Comment: And what if I want to use dot (.) as thousands separator?

eg. 80.908,563?

Comment: Just updated both regexs, previously they allowed inputs ending in a comma with no decimal digits (e.g. `1.000,`)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a simple `if` statement containing two conditions.

- `!parseInt(number)` - the number is zero
- `number > parseInt(number)` - the number has more than 3 decimal digits (notice that I previously multiplied the number by 1000)

```
function checkNumber(number) {
    number = Math.abs( parseFloat(number) * 1000 );
    if (!parseInt(number) || number > parseInt(number)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * EXAMPLES
 */
checkNumber(0.872);   //true
checkNumber(1.00001); //false
checkNumber(0.00);    //false
checkNumber(0.87);    //true
checkNumber(0.87215); //false
```